# laravel Controller error when using Request in function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I make controller by using `php artisan make:controller newsController --resource`

And after that when I go to my controller in function `index`, I want to add `Request $request`

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   

}
```

It's return error:

> Declaration of
>   App\Http\Controllers\Admin\NewsController::index(Illuminate\Http\Request
>   $request) should be compatible with
>   App\Http\Controllers\Controller::index()

How to fix it? I try many way but it still didn't work!

**EDIT** — *Controller*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

**UPDATED** — *Routes*

```
Route::post('admin/news', 'Admin\NewsController@store');
Route::resource('admin/news', 'Admin\NewsController');
```

Comment: Make sure you have "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" as namespace

Comment: @ankitpatel I updated my question and already add it

Comment: can you please share your route file?

Comment: updated  I@ankitpatel

Comment: did you run the command "composer dump-autoload" ?

Comment: also make sure you have that route by running php artisan route:list

Comment: yes I've route runing in route:list and I alredy dump auto-load It still got same error

Comment: @ankitpatel this happen in function index only when I put Request into create function It's not show up an error not sure why lol

Comment: I think, in resource controller's method `index` is used for `get()` any data. Not for post any data. I mean you cannot use `Request $request` in that `index` method! Please read this table docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers Hope this help you!

Comment: I not sure because in 5.4 I try to use resouce with Request and it work fine, the reason that I want to use post because I want to make serach function

Comment: @HirenGohel I alredy look into it  and so I've to create new controller without resouce for geting request right ?

Comment: @test1321 Please check my answer below, let me know after you checked!

Comment: `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` is there any controllers `namespace` in your `controller`?

Comment: why did you add a `index` method to your base controller. this is just an issue with inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple, just create your `Resource controller` without the index route Or Create new get route, like this:

```
Route::resource('admin/news', 'Admin\NewsController', ['except' => ['index']]);
```

Then add your route before the resource declaration, something like this:

```
Route::post('admin/news', 'Admin\NewsController@index');

Route::resource('admin/news', 'Admin\NewsController', ['except' => ['index']]);
```

Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't require any Laravel work arounds.

**Fix:**

**a)** Remove the `index` method from the base controller

or

**b)** Make the `index` method in the base controller take a `Illuminate\Http\Request` as an argument and use that same method signature in every controller's `index` method that inherited from the base in the entire application.

or

**c)** Figure out why there is an `index` method defined in the base in the first place and, if needed, move it to a trait to use in child classes instead. (allows you to override the method completely)

**b** is not a good option, it is just to illustrate a point

**Issue demonstrated:**

```
class Foo
{
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

> Declaration of Bar::index(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) should be compatible with Foo::index()

Answer (score 1):

You want to override the `index` action.

You also want to pass parameters into this `index` action.

The `App\Http\Controllers\Controller::index()` does not take parameters.

So they are not "compatible".

Try this "helper-funtion" way:

```
public function index() {

$request = request() // use the helper function

// ...you code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `index` from resources and define route with different method name before or after resource:

```
    Route::get('resources', 'ResourceController@getResources');
    Route::resource('resources', 'ResourceController', $restResource)->except(['index']);
```